# Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default

Tags: php, zend-framework

> Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default
>   I installed `zend 2 framework` with `AuthDoctrine` module. As you can see I am getting the above error when try to visit

```
http://localhost/test/public/auth-doctrine/index/login
```

I am getting error in my `Module.php` file.

If you are using `DoctrineORMModule`:

```
return $serviceManager->get('doctrine.authenticationservice.odm_default');
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this?